# Unable to restore database using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms, backup

I am unable to restore database in form of .bak files using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express.

It gives following error message:

```
Too many backup devices specified for backup or restore; only 64 are allowed.    
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

Can you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server did you use to create this backup? Do you have SQL Server 2000 installed?

Comment: I took backup from my webhosting server. It was SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to restore backup on older version of MS SQL Server than the backup was made. For example, if you made backup on MS SQL Server 2008 and restore on MS SQL 2005.

In this case you need to install the correct version of MS SQL Server and move the data by Export/Import functionality.